# Django: from request.user to derived class

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I derived from `django.contrib.auth.models.User` to extend each user with app specific data using [multi table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

```
class FooUser(User):
    telephone_number = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

What is the most easy way to get a `foo_user` instance from `request.user`?

Answer (score 3):

In the very paragraph that you linked to, it is indicated:

> If you have a Place that is also a Restaurant, you can get from the
>   Place object to the Restaurant object by using the lower-case version
>   of the model name:
>
> ```
> >>> p = Place.objects.get(id=12)
> # If p is a Restaurant object, this will give the child class:
> >>> p.restaurant <Restaurant: ...>
> ```

So in your case, just do: `request.user.foouser`

Of course, as also indicated in the documentation, this will work only if the current user was created as a FooUser and has associated data in the corresponding table. If not, `FooUser.DoesNotExist` will be raised.